# How to adjust pen sensitivity on Surface3

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface

When trying to adjust pen sensitivity using the Surface App in Windows 10 I get the following message:

[image: screenshot of surface app in win10]
Refreshing the stated window 3 times has no effect. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but just for clarity, can you confirm that the OS does detect the pen

Comment: Yes, have you actually paired the pen with the OS?  Go to settings, make sure Bluetooth is on, see if it is listed as paired.  If not, hold the pen top button down for about 10 seconds until it's light blinks, the tap Pair in the Bluetooth settings.

Comment: Yes, it is paired. The top button opens OneNote.